# Indenting a paragraph only

Tags: indentation

I am a beginner using Tex Maker and I want to write `1. Linear` (then text will be right indented starting from the L in Linear). Then `2. Partial` will be in same indentation as before (without right indentation). Is there an easy way to do this? I tried using answers to other questions but they are complicated and didn't work.

Comment: Tex Maker * not it is related to all the Latex format

Comment: @user3599420, I don't understand what you are looking for due to the terms "Linear" and "Partial". Can you add a picture or sketch of what you try to achieve?

Comment: Linear and Partial are just titles. I have like 2 titles and I want the text beneath them to be indented a bit to the right. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: I believe the OP is wanting to configure TeXmaker to indent the *source code* in this manner – I don't believe output is involved in the question.

Comment: @SeanAllred, I was uncertain about the scope of this question too. But it turned out to be about the output: "Tex Maker * not it is related to all the Latex format" (user3599420, 2 hours ago)

Comment: @Ruben Unfortunately those are just words to me – I can't make any sense of them.  :(

Comment: @SeanAllred, I rectified the sentence for me as follows: Texmaker [resp. the editor] is not related to what I am trying to achieve in LaTeX. It's about the LaTeX format, i.e. typeset text.

Comment: @Ruben Alright, I can see that :) Thankfully, it's made doubly clear by the screenshot that's been edited-in.

Comment: But I want the whole text under 1 to be adjusted not just the first sentence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as a sectioning issue, as far as you try to markup a certain part of your document with a title. Normally you would say:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{lipsum} %to add a blindtext

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Linear}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\paragraph{Partial}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

At the moment this won't match your design criteria. Add the following lines between `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\begin{document}` to fix it:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\@arabic\c@paragraph.}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\let\ltx@paragraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \ltx@paragraph{#2\\}
  \else
    \ltx@paragraph[#1]{#2\\}
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

[image]

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\edef\ltx@parindent{\the\parindent}
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@seccntformat##1{\csname the##1\endcsname.\hspace{1.3ex}}
  \leftskip\ltx@parindent
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{-\ltx@parindent}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {0.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}%
\def\endparagraph{\par\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{paragraph}{Linear}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{paragraph}

\begin{paragraph}{Partial}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this gives me: LaTeX Error: File 'lipsum.sty' not found and I have installed the packaged when it asks for the installation

Comment: It seems like your distro is broken as you have the same problem with the `enumitem` package. Both are very common packages and its really the exception that they can't be installed automatically from the repository.

Comment: any suggestions? :( I am using TexMaker

Comment: Yes! Search for package-installing-questions on this site. And moreover for a general introduction to LaTeX. You will need to understand a little better how the LaTeX software bundle works in detail to fix your porblem, i.e. TeXmaker has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I canceled out the `lipsum` package. Now, the example does not rely on any packages. Does it compile now?

Comment: it compiles but the first line of the paragraph only is indented

Comment: what I meant is as shown in the first example of @cfr answer

Comment: Does the update cover anything you want?

Comment: no I put a picture in my original post that is what I am getting. I want that part to be indented right (apart from the 1..)

Comment: The picture is incomplete! But, from what I can see it looks like what I proposed in my first approach. Isn't it?

Comment: I know it is my report I can't put it online yet so I put the part which is required. I don't know what you mean but what I want is as cfr said below (first example) but his approach still doesn't work because of the packages

Comment: cfrs first approach and my updated version differ only in the font of the headings, i.e. "1. Linear" and "2. Partial"...

Comment: I don't know it isn't working for me :( But thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working? You really need to be more accurate. This will amplify your chance to get better help.

Comment: The text is not being indented, it remains:

1. Linear
bla bla bla 

where the text starts under 1. instead of under the L

Comment: Can you please send me a zip of your `.tex` + all auxiliary files + a screenshot of what happens on your machine via e-mail (see my profile)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19026/discussion-between-user3599420-and-ruben).

Comment: hey I found the problem I removed the \usepackage{parskip} that I was using to remove the automatic indentation of the paragraphs and it worked, however, is there a solution how I can solve both problems?

Comment: The `parskip` package did not appear in my code! For the future: Please try examples first without adding stuff that isn't there before you claim that they don't work. Moreover you can name the packages you depend on or the solution must be compatible with in the OP.

Comment: I didn't say that yours did not work, it wasn't working with my code since I need the parskip package to remove the automatic indentations of new paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make a numbered list? If so, I'm not sure quite what pattern you want but perhaps it is one of these two:

[image: two enumerations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Linear

      \kant[1]

    \item Partial

      \kant[2]
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., labelindent=\parindent, itemindent=-\parindent]
    \item Linear

      \kant[1]

    \item Partial

      \kant[2]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is \kant[1] ?

Comment: @user3599420 `\kant[1]` just produces a nonsense paragraph from the `kantlipsum` package, that's used just for this purpose (in other words, you don't need it, unless you want to fill your document with deep philosophical thoughts).

Comment: I see :) however I used this but it says file enumitem.sty not found even after it asks to install the package and i accept... i search about it and it looks a common problem. Do you know about this matter?

Comment: @user3599420 As Ruben notes in response to comments on that answer, there is something wrong with your installation. I'm taking it that you are using MiKTeX, which I'm not familiar with, but `enumitem` is a really common package. You should fix the basic problem because it is almost certain to cause you all kinds of headaches as you are otherwise going to be unable to use lots of packages which would make life easier. I know MiKTeX has a package manager as well as on-the-fly installation support, and there are lots of questions on this topic on the site.